# How to write (a^n-1) in c programming

Tags: c

I want to write (a^n-1) in c programming. I wrote `pow(a,n-1)` and the output is
wrong. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main() {

    float a, r,n;
    float sum = 0;
    a = 1.04*pow(a, n-1);
    r = 1.02*pow(1.04,-1);
    n = 2;

    sum = 360000*pow(1.04,n)-50000*(a * (1 - pow((r), n ))) / (1- (r));


    printf("\n%.2f", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

The correct output should be `286376` but the program showed `2903773`

Comment: Sophie, Once answers appear, it is bad form to change the question.  Question rolled back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every C program executes line by line. So, at the time when compiler came on

```
a = 1.04*pow(a, n-1);
```

this line, variable `a` and `n` was not assigned with any value, resulted in giving you a garbage value...

So, the problem is, you had not assigned values in variables, and still, you were using them.

You have to first assign values in variables before using them. Otherwise, they will pick any garbage value from memory (Any Random number).

Assign value in `a` and `n` and try again.

**Edit:** As [chux's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568473/how-to-write-an-1-in-c-programming/52568651?noredirect=1#comment92074400_52568651) suggests, if your program is supposed to give `286376` as output, then value of `a` should be `1` and value of `n` should be `2`.

So, your correct code would be this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    float a=1, r, n=2;
    float sum = 0;
    a = 1.04*pow(a, n-1) ;
    r = 1.02*pow(1.04,-1);
    sum = 360000*pow(1.04,n)-50000*(a * (1 - pow((r), n ))) / (1- (r));
    printf("\n%.2f", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pow(a, n-1) translates into exp(log(a) * (n-1)) which isn't precisely the same.. You can try to round the output like this:

```
round(pow(a, n-1))
```

Comment: "pow(a, n-1) translates into exp(log(a) * (n-1))" --> not quite.   `pow(negative, some_whole_number)` is well defined.  `log(negative)` is a problem.